# Regex to check with starts with [ and end with ]

Tags: java, regex, string-matching

I have some text in a file like this:

```
[ABM-100]
0x00,Hours    
0x01,Minutes  
0x06,T2       

[CO2SMO]
1   ,Instrument
2   ,Time               
3   ,AAI
```

I want to get the text between [ and ], like ABM-100 and CO2SMO.
I try using regex to match, but the result is

```
[ABM-100]
0x00,Hours    
0x01,Minutes  
0x06,T2       

[CO2SMO]
```

I've tried the following

```
line.matches("^\\[.*.\\]$")
```

Comment: Your question is confusing. `matches` returns only true or false, not text. Also if `lines` would represent text build from many lines then dot `.` wouldn't be able to accept them since it can't match `\n` or `\r`.

Comment: How about something like this: \[([^\]]*)\]. https://regex101.com/r/vA9wV2/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't show your full code, but the code `line.matches("^\\[.*.\\]$")` implies that you are checking each line separately.

If you want to capture is piece of the matched text, you should use a capture group.

Since you are using `matches()`, you don't need the anchors (`^$`), and the extra `.` is superfluous.

This shows how to do it:

```
String[] lines = { "[ABM-100]",
                   "0x00,Hours    ",
                   "0x01,Minutes  ",
                   "0x06,T2       ",
                   "",
                   "[CO2SMO]",
                   "1   ,Instrument",
                   "2   ,Time               ",
                   "3   ,AAI  " };
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*)\\]");
for (String line : lines) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
    if (m.matches())
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

*Output*

```
ABM-100
CO2SMO
```

---

If `line` does not represent one line at a time, but rather the entire text, you need to use `find()`, and make the `^$` anchors match beginning and end of line by specifying the `MULTILINE` flag:

```
String text = "[ABM-100]\n" +
              "0x00,Hours    \n" +
              "0x01,Minutes  \n" +
              "0x06,T2       \n" +
              "\n" +
              "[CO2SMO]\n" +
              "1   ,Instrument\n" +
              "2   ,Time               \n" +
              "3   ,AAI  \n";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^\\[(.*)\\]$", Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
while (m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
```

Output is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a regex for this since you can just do `line.startsWith("[") && line.endsWith("]");` and it will be much faster.

Comment: I think you mean `line.endsWith("]);`

Answer (score 0):

`.*` is greedy which means that your regex will try to match maximal possible range between first `[` it finds and `]`. You can try making `.*` reluctant by adding `?` like `.*?`. You can also replace `.` with `[^\\]]` to avoid matching `]` inside.

Also `matches` checks if entire string matches regex, it doesn't return match. I suspect that you may want to use

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(yourRegex);
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
while(m.find()){
    String match = m.group();
    //do what you want with match like:
    System.out.println(match);
}
```